# Is it safe to use Guava Resources.getResource() in production?

Tags: java, classloader, guava

We can see a warning from IDE when we try to use Guava [`Resources.getResource()`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/io/Resources.java#L193):

> 'getResource(java.lang.String)' is declared in unstable class 'com.google.common.io.Resources' marked with @Beta

Is it safe to be used in production?

Comment: Write a test to ensure it does (and continues to do) what you need it to do.

Comment: Please don't be discouraged by the title of the duplicate, it asks basically the same question ("Can/should I use a class annotated with @Beta in Guava") and the answer should help you decide.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, yes, it's safe. Guava libraries are used extensively in Google, so any changes have to be carefully considered, even for `@Beta` classes, even just for the internal use case, with the net result that this is very unlikely to be changed in a way that substantially changes its semantics.

If you are worried about an API being unstable, you can write a test to ensure that it does - and, more importantly, continues to do - what you need it to do.

With that said, the body of `Resources.getResource(String)` method is trivial - it basically just does `someClass.getResource(String)`, and throws an exception if the resulting URL is null. You could simply reimplement that method yourself, then you are in control of its stability.